# form value is not added to database

Tags: java, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i8rD.png)

i am using angular to insert the new customer object by calling the java api but the customer object is not inserted.The customer object submitted from form is not inserted in the database. however the getCustomers() method does works. The form data is being fetched upto addCustomer(customer:Customer) method of the data.service.ts but it is not added to the database.

```
1. CustomerController.java

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders ="*" )
public class CustomerResource {
@Autowired
private CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl;

@PostMapping("/customers")
public Customer addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
    return customerServiceImpl.addCustomer(customer);
}
```

2.create-customer.component.html

#### Create Customer Form

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label> <input type="text"
                                                   class="form-control" 
id="firstName" required

[(ngModel)]="customer.firstName" name="firstName">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label> <input type="text"
                                                 class="form-control" 
id="lastname" required

[(ngModel)]="customer.lastName" name="lastname">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address"> Address</label> <input type="text"
                                                 class="form-control" 
id="address" required

[(ngModel)]="customer.address" name="address">
</div>


<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
  <a routerLink="/customers" class="btn btn-success" 
(click)="onSubmit()">Submit</a>

</div>
</form>  


3.Create-customer.component.ts

@Component({
selector: 'app-create-customer',
templateUrl: './create-customer.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./create-customer.component.css']
})



export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
customer = new Customer;
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private locaion: Location) 
{ }
ngOnInit() {
}

add(): void {
/*console.log(this.customer);*/
this.dataService.addCustomer(this.customer);
}

onSubmit(): void {
this.add();
}
goBack(): void {
this.locaion.back();
}
}  


4.data-service.ts 

const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
private customersUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/customers';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.customersUrl)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('getCustomers', []))
  );
}


addCustomer (customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
console.log(customer);
return this.http.post<Customer>(this.customersUrl, customer, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError<Customer>('addCustomer'))
);
}

private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
  console.error(error); // log to console instead
  return of(result as T);
};
}
}
```

Comment: What the data you post to the server?

Comment: firstname, lastname and address

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of post data from Browser Developer Tool?

Comment: i have added the screenshot above in the question section

Comment: Whether there is the same data in the network tab of the Browser Developer Tool?

like this http://prntscr.com/m37xxc

Comment: yes the data in the network tab is same. https://prnt.sc/m38bec

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling `addCustomer`, and you have to make sure that the data you are sending as you would expect it to know the problem is in Angular(FrontEnd) or Java(Backend)